# Uploading multiple files with Fetch and FormData APIs

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ecmascript-6, multipartform-data, react-dropzone

I'm trying to use the native [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) APIs to upload multiple files at once to the server but I can't for the life of me get it to work. Here's what I've got:

```
// acceptedFiles are File objects coming from `react-dropzone`.
function handleSubmit(acceptedFiles) {
  const data = new FormData();

  for (const file of acceptedFiles) {
    data.append('files', file, file.name);
  }

  return fetch('https://example.com/api/upload', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data,      
  });
}
```

But what my Rails server receives is this:

```
Parameters: {"files"=>#
<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007feb347becc0 @tempfile=#
<Tempfile:/var/folders/kl/y1jrp7zs55sbx075jjjl3p280000gn/T/RackMultipart201
71112-6486-1ftkufy.mp4>, @original_filename="SampleVideo_1280x720_5mb.mp4",
 @content_type="video/mp4", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; 
name=\"files\"; filename=\"SampleVideo_1280x720_5mb.mp4\"\r\nContent-Type:
 video/mp4\r\n">}
```

In other words, it looks like `files` is actually just one file. But the [docs for `FormData` say that append should append multiple files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append#example).

So what's going wrong?

Comment: This might be relevant: https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/566

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The solution was to change `files` to `files[]`:

```
// acceptedFiles are File objects coming from `react-dropzone`.
function handleSubmit(acceptedFiles) {
  const data = new FormData();

  for (const file of acceptedFiles) {
    data.append('files[]', file, file.name);
  }

  return fetch('https://example.com/api/upload', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data,      
  });
}
```

Comment: cant believe with so many examples, no had put []

Answer (score 0):

For sending multiple files i have done it a little bit different because my php api endpoint says there was only one file if i send it with `formdata.append('files[]', file)`

```html
<input type="file" multiple data-sender="{{ user.hashIdentifier }}">
```

```
/** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
const input = document.querySelector('input[type=file]');
input.addEventListener('input', function listener(event){

  if(input.files.length > 0){
    const formData = new FormData();

    for(let i = 0; i < input.files.lenght; i++){
      formData.append(`file_${i}`, input.files[i]);
    }

    // my endpoint should know who sends the file

    formData.append('identify', input.dataSet.sender);

    sendData(formData);

  } else {
    console.error('no files selected');
  }   
});

/** 
 * sending the formData Object with all files to the server
 * @param {FormData} formData 
 */
function sendData(formData) {
  const url = '/api/saveFiles';
  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
  };

  fetch(url, options)
    .fetch((response) => {
      if(!response.ok) {
        throw Error(response.statusText);
      }

      return response.json();
    })
    .fetch((data) => {
      console.log('success', data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    })

}
```

my php is a symfony project and looks like that:

```php
/**
 * @param Request $request (inject symfonys http request)
 * @param FileService $fileService (inject my own FileService)
 * @returns Response (symfony http Response)
 */
#[Route('/api/saveFiles', name: 'api_saveFiles', methods: ['POST'])]
public function api_saveFiles(Request $request, FileService $fileService): Response
{
  $statusCode = 409; // Conflict

  $result = array();
  
  /** @var FileBag */
  $fileBag = $request->files;

  if($fileBag->count() > 0) {
    $statusCode=200;
    $result['numberOfFiles'] = $fileBag->count();
    $result['keys'] = $fileBag->keys();

    $result['infos'] = array();
    foreach($fileBag->keys() as $key){
      try {
        $file = $fileBag->get($key);
        $fileInfo = $fileService->saveFile($file); // saves the file and gives back some infos
        $result['infos'][$fileInfo];
      } catch(Exception $ex) {
        // TODO: handle errors
      }    

    }
  }

  return new JsonResponse($result, $statusCode);
}
```

in the attemps i tried it with `formData.append('files[]', file);` php  has only  captured the last file.

Answer (score 0):

```
// acceptedFiles are File objects coming from `react-dropzone`.
function handleSubmit(acceptedFiles) {
  const data = new FormData();

  for (const [index, file] of acceptedFiles) {
    data.append('files' + index, file, file.name);
  }

  return fetch('https://example.com/api/upload', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data,      enter code here
  });
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).