# How to get uploaded file in Flask?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, file-upload

Currently, I want to upload some pictures from the frontend to the backend,
and I can upload these images correctly, but I don't know how to get these photos in the backend.
Here, I upload the images using FormData in the frontend

```js
const url = "http://localhost:5000/hotel";
    const data = new FormData();
    var photos = document.querySelector("input[type='file'][multiple]");
    console.log(photos.files);
    data.append("photos", photos.files);
    fetch(url, {
      headers: new Headers({
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }),
      mode: "cors",
      method: "post",
      body: data
    });
```

now, I tried to get these files in the backend using flask.

```py
@app.route('/hotel', methods=['POST'])
def add_hotel():
    print(request.form)
    print(request.data)
    print(request.files)
```

The print result is something like this:

```py
ImmutableMultiDict([])
b'------WebKitFormBoundaryo54yZ5CoNX8dQZZ3\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="photos"\r\n\r\n[object FileList]\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryo54yZ5CoNX8dQZZ3--\r\n'
ImmutableMultiDict([])
```

and I think these images are stored in the request.data, but how can I save these data like the normal file in request.files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading multiple files with Fetch and FormData APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47253661/uploading-multiple-files-with-fetch-and-formdata-apis)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I checked my code again, I found that the problem in the frontend, when send request using form data, you should not use the header `"Content-Type": "application/json"`, and just put form data in the body

Answer (score 0):

You have to use request.files.getlist. See [/how-to-upload-multiple-files-using-flask-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35649770/how-to-upload-multiple-files-using-flask-in-python/39443137) for details and further improvements.

Comment: Thank you  for answering, i found the problem is in the frontend, i should not specify content type when using formdata